# How to set an alias for an identifier in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, alias

***Concept example:***

```
declare @x varchar(max)

set @x = 'top 1 *'

select @x from table
```

---

***Result wanted:***

For the script to function as:

```
select top 1 * from table
```

To return the first row in table.

---

***Actual result:***

The script functions as:

```
select 'top 1 *' from table
```

Many rows return with values 'top 1 *'

---

***Use case:***

In a more complex scenario, the x variable would be a much longer string that would need to be called upon several times later in the script. Instead of pasting that long variable over and over, I want to set an alias for it. Is this possible?

Comment: You can't use it like that - look into dynamic SQL

Comment: Identifiers (i.e. object names) are not strings. It's roughly the same in any language. That's why, for instance, you can't use prepared statement placeholders to specify them.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález My apologies, I'm not familiar with the technical terms (completely self taught). Am I correct in understanding that my question should have been phrased "How to set an alias for an identifier in SQL?" Thanks.

Comment: No apologies needed, I only wanted to share additional info. Right now you just want dynamic SQL as already pointed out, which only consists on composing code inside a string and asking MySQL to execute it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
declare @x varchar(max), @sql varchar(max)

set @x = 'top 1 *'

set @sql = 'select '+ @x +' from table'

PRINT @sql;

--EXECUTE (@sql) -- Uncomment this when you are sure of your query
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Comment: I'm wondering now if there's another method, or more efficient way of doing this? This method does work well for shorter scripts, but isn't practical otherwise (as mentioned in the "use case" section).

Comment: @Jonathan `@sql` here is just a variable with text. You can define as many variables as you want, or manipulate them as much as you need. In any case, dynamic SQL tends to be normally generated by other languages (C, Java, PHP, whatever...).